# How to add the axis mar files as a runtime library in a maven project using m2e in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, maven, apache-axis, ws-addressing

I have a Maven project in eclipse and I am using the eclipse m2e plugin to manage the Maven dependencies in eclipse. 
The m2e plugin is smart enough to let eclipse treat the maven dependencies as a eclipse library and hence I am able to launch and debug my samples and test code from the eclipse.

This all works fine until I have to work with .mar files from axis (specifically addressing.mar). Now this is mentioned as an dependency in the pom.xml, but eclipse is not able to recognize this as a library during runtime until i explicitly add it to the classpath. Is there a way to let eclipse become aware of addressing.mar as a library that is coming from the maven dependencies.

Comment: This is an old post, I know. But, I am facing the same issue with an axis2 project I am working on. Has a solution been found for this?